# $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ is continuous and $f^2$ is uniformly continuous then f is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, continuity, uniform-continuity

Let $f$ be a continuous function from  $\mathbb{R}$ to $[0,\infty)$ and $g(x)= f(x)^2$ is uniformly continuous. Then I want to prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous. I would like to mention one thing that is $f(x)^2=f(x)f(x)$, not the composition $f\circ f$.

> My approach: Since $f(x)\geq 0$ we have $f(x)=\sqrt{g(x)}$. Now for any arbitrary $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ we have $f(x)+f(y)=m$ and therefore $f(x)-f(y)= \frac{g(x)-g(y)}{m)}$  this gives that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Where do we appeal to uniform continuity of $f^2$?

Comment: Composition of uniformly continuous functions is uniformly continuous, how this is giving answer of my question?

Comment: @AnneBauval if f And g are uniformly continuous then their composition is also. But we can say anything conversly and in my problem

Comment: $f=\sqrt~\circ f^2$.

Comment: @AnneBauval Is $\sqrt$ uniformly continuous? How do we claim this?  Please let me know whether my approach is correct or not?

Comment: What happens when you try to prove that $\sqrt{\;}$ is uniformly continuous?  This is a special case of the question.  And, according to Anne's comments, will imply the whole thing.

Comment: Here is a complete duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1576885 Your approach was not correct (see first comment by Alvin + there is no reason why $f(x)-f(y)= \frac{g(x)-g(y)}{f(x)+f(y)}$ would "give that $f$ is uniformly continuous" + $m$ could even be $0$ for some $(x,y)$'s).

Comment: @AnneBauval thanks, fixed (it was within 5 minutes).

Comment: @AnneBauval thanks I got the answer. This is a duplicate question. Please let me know what should I do in such scenario.

Comment: You can delete your question if you want (by clicking on "Delete" on the line "Share
Cite
Edit
Following
Close 1
Flag" below your post).