# $f(x)$ uniformly continuous at $(0,1)$ iff $g(x) = xf(x)$ is uniformly continuous at $(0,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis

For $f(x)$ positive continuous function at $(0,1)$

Is it true or false that:

$f(x)$ uniformly continuous at $(0,1)$ iff $g(x) = xf(x)$ is uniformly continuous at $(0,1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f(x)={1\over x}$ is not uniformly continuous, gut $g(x)=xf(x)=1$ is uniformly continuous

Comment: pretty simple, thank you for the help. 
Is there is a rule for arithmetic of uniformly continuous functions? lets say, if fx uniformly continuous and gx also, therefore, can i conclude about fx*gx that it is also uniformly continuous?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345480/product-of-two-uniformly-continuous-functions-is-uniformly-continuous