# The limit at the end-point of an open interval, for a uniformly continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

If $f: (a,b)\to\mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous and $\{x_n\}$ in the domain tends to $b$, then why does $\{f(x_n)\}$ have a limit?

Comment: See here:   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538518/uniform-continuous-function-proof/539122#539122

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because  $x_n$ is Cauchy sequence then $f(x_n)$ is Cauchy sequence due to uniform continuouity. And hence $f(x_n)$ is convergant.

Comment: Thanks. Full explanation in Christian's answer linked in the first comment above.